# Latest ADT and sdk tools installed but still asking for latest sdk tools

Tags: android

I have just installed Eclipse Juno and installed the ADT plugin 20.0.3 but I am still getting this message on every eclipse launch saying "This version of ADT requires android sdk tools in revision 20.0.0 or above.current revision is 18.0.0.Please upgrade your sdk to latest version".The sdk tools I pointed to in preferences are up to date because tomorrow I was working on Eclipse Indigo(Which also had ADT 20.0.3 installed) and had all the sdk tools updated.I just pointed the same sdk folder in Juno.Please help thank you

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to just configure another version of eclipse.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it.Are you I should not use this latest Juno version?

Comment: Just said get a clean version of the eclipse you want to use and configure it from the start. Sometimes preferences in eclipse break.

Comment: Well that would be plan B:).Is it possible that because I have two eclipse installations in the system they are conflicting in any way?.An installation from start would take an entire day because my net is slow these days.:(

Comment: Eclipse doesn't really install. It just creates configuration in the workspace and in the path you unzipped in. They don't conflict with each other either. I have at least 4 eclipses configured here for different purposes. But if your juno is working and would stick with it, that is what i use nowadays.

Comment: As it turns out the indigo is giving me the same above error.What is this now?.I didn't even touch it.

Comment: My guess would be that your adt version installed as plugin in eclipse needs to be updated. Go to check updates in eclipse and see if ADT has a new version.

Comment: both indigo and juno have latest adt installed(v. 20.0.3)

Comment: If you say adt is updated and SDK tools is updated then ignore the messages, everything should still run fine. When you open the android sdk manager from eclipse it says it is updated? If it does as I said just ignore it.

Comment: well I can but when I create a new android project,it says that sdk tools are out dated and you need to update them.I don't understand this, yesterday I created new android projects and everything was fine.Now both are not working!.This does n't make any sense.Atleast indigo should work

Answer (score 45):

Actually, the solution involves no delete or download of the whole installer. 
After you update the Eclipse ADT, you just have to update the SDK tools in the SDK manager too. 
The trick is open SDK manager -> Packages menu -> Reload. Then the latest revision will be available to update. It's just that simple, but actually annoying at first.

Comment: Please accept this answer, because I just had the same issue and I'm familiar with launching the SDK manager from within Eclipse but missed the vital "Reload" step.

Comment: The question is, why doesn't it "Reload" by default! Sigh.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue as well except I was getting it for ADT 21 and the message was as follows:

"This version of ADT requires Android SDK tools revision 21.0.0 rc9 or above".

I was not able to update to SDK tools 21.0.0 rc9 using SDK Manager. I found that I had to re-install the SDK Tools for Windows by downloading [installer_r1-windows.exe](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21-windows.exe)

I found this link on the [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) page.

After installing this, my SDK Manager showed SDK Tools 21 as being installed and gave me the option to download the Android 4.2 Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

go to C:// -> Program Files -> Android

There should only be one folder there, I had more than one (from previous SDK downloads).

Eclipse is confused and is using the wrong one. Delete the outdated folder(s), keep the most recent SDK download.

Re-launch Eclipse, it should pop up an error saying it couldn't find your SDK folder. It give you a button labelled "preferences" in that error. Go to preferences and adjust the path to the only folder found in program files -> android.

Answer (score 0):

Although I had set the proxy settings in the Eclipse Network settings, they weren't used by the SDK Manager. The SDK Manager has its own under "Tools --> Options". It would be great if it could in future versions instead use the default Eclipse proxy settings to avoid this problem.