# Android SDK Manager not working

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

On starting Eclipse I am getting a message

```
This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 21.0.0 rc9 or above.
Current version is 10.0.0.
Please update your SDK tools to latest SDk version.
```

So on clicking Open SDK Manager button nothing happens & in console I get this message.

```
[2012-12-27 16:15:06 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead.
```

Why?

My SDK manager window doesn't open so I can not update SDK Tools.
I am working on Ubuntu 10.10 with Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to locate where is your Android SDK Manager (the path where you installed first your SDK). Suppose that it is `/opt/android-sdk-linux` and substitute where needed:

From a terminal, try to execute

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

With that you will get a Android SDK Manager windows where you can upgrade your SDK elements (including the SDK Manager and tools). Probably the integration of Android SDK Manager with Eclipse has changed from version 10 to 21, making Eclipse unable to start it.

P.S. Using `sudo` could be unnecessary, depending on the path and the privileges that your user have on it.

Comment: I opened the Android SDK and AVD Manager from cmd line.But when I look for Available packages, so In Android repository I only find Android SDK Tools,revision 15.Not the revision 21 or any other.Please help

Comment: Try to upgrade first to r15. Then, maybe it is possible to upgrade to newer releases from that point. Good luck

Comment: I upgraded to r15.Now it is showing only for revision 20.Why am I not getting all the revision available?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose that some major change is introduced in one version in its way to upgrade.

Comment: OK Finally after upgrading to r20.I got r21 to install.Now its working fine.

Comment: Great! Enjoy programming :-)

Comment: On windows, this will be something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\"SDK Manager.exe".  Your path may be diferent, depending on your install.

Comment: I update my own sdk 3 times, the tool is finally 22.3

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the adt-bundle from android then delete and unzip the bundle again and try opening the eclipse. I faced a similar problem . I got rid of this error by doing the above step .
Hope it helps you :):) .. And remember JAVA 7 is incompatible(not tested and recommend) with android eclipse .. so use JAVA 6 .

-Preeya

Comment: Try doing a clean uninstall of Java and eclipse with android sdk and then try to install the packages and see if the problem disappears . Seems like the problem is while uninstalling all data of the package  is not cleared.( Do reboots if necessary) .

Comment: Sometimes, adding proxy settings in Eclipse and restart, would help.

Answer (score 0):

[Latest ADT and sdk tools installed but still asking for latest sdk tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220460/latest-adt-and-sdk-tools-installed-but-still-asking-for-latest-sdk-tools)

"Actually, the solution involves no delete or download of the whole installer. After you update the Eclipse ADT, you just have to update the SDK tools in the SDK manager too. The trick is open SDK manager -> Packages menu -> Reload. Then the latest revision will be available to update. It's just that simple, but actually annoying at first."

It worked for me

Comment: Where is the `Package Menu`?

Comment: is the menu on the top left (window menu). "Reload" is the last option

Answer (score 0):

Check path in Window -- Preferences -- Android. Must be right