# Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have installed ADT Bundle on my computer, but every time I try to access SDK Manager from Eclipse I get the below error and nothing happens.

```
(Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead)
```

However, if I try to access the SDK Manager from outside Eclipse it opens just fine.

I removed the ADT Bundle completely from my computer, and went on to manually install Eclipse and the Android SDK Manager, but upon trying to open SDK Manager from Eclipse I got the same error once again and nothing happened.

Comment: And yes, I have the 64bit Trio (Eclipse, OS and Java)

Comment: On Starting Eclipse are you getting this error message - "This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 21.0.0 rc9 or above.
Current version is 10.0.0.
Please update your SDK tools to latest SDk version.
" ?

Comment: Yes. I get this message even though I update the SDK Tools to Rev. 22.3.

Comment: If you are using the adt-bundle from android then delete and unzip the bundle again and try opening the eclipse.

Comment: I tried to delete and unzip the bundle again. The same error pops up. I also tried to manually install Eclipse and Android SDK without the Bundle, and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in the below worked,

[Android SDK Manager not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053450/android-sdk-manager-not-working)

I executed android.bat in /android-sdk/tools/ on windows machine and sdk manager opened.