# Android sdk access is denied

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When i open eclipse it says

```
This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 21.0.0 rc9 or above.
Current revision is 20.0.0
Please update your SDK Tools to the latest version
```

So i click the open sdk manager button and but the only things i see are

```
Androids SDK Tools Rev 20 installed
Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 12 Installed
```

No options to update and no platforms to install. SO i try running the android.bat as the administrator and i see in the cmd 13 lines of Access is denied

I'm pretty new to android development and eclipse and so now i have no idea what to do

I'm on windows 7 and it is eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution involves no delete or download of the whole installer. After you update the Eclipse ADT, you just have to update the SDK tools in the SDK manager too. The trick is open SDK manager -> Packages menu -> Reload. Then the latest revision will be available to update. It's just that simple, but actually annoying at first.
still you are facing the problem than please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220460/latest-adt-and-sdk-tools-installed-but-still-asking-for-latest-sdk-tools)

Comment: I haven't been trying to do this through eclipse I've been using the sdk manager all along. I just uninstalled 20 and installed 21.0.1 and its trying to get me to downgrade to 20 and i still don't get any options to download additional packages

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the packages. it will solve the issue.

Check [this](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) link.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks